# License key comparison for new and old model (key not matches)

Tags: c#, serialization, license-key

I have 2 xml files (old and new license). One has an Enable field and the other does not. I have method to check  is license is valid. I check if the key of the delivered license is the same as the one calculated. Because the old license does not have Enabled field, the old license key never matches (because the model now has an Enabled field). I don't know how to solve this problem. The new license must have the field enabled.
to be honest I don't even know what to google...

I am using MD5.

Model (new)

```
public string Name {get;set;}
public bool isEnabled {get; set;}
public DateTime Date {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Enable field as nullable. And change the logic of the check method so that if Enable is null, then do not use it. To do this, provide two ways - the old and the new checking method.

```
class License 
{ 
   [XmlElement("Enable")]
   bool? Enable { get; set; } = null; // '?' means that value can be true, false or null.
   // ...
}

bool Check(License license)
{
   if (license.Enable == null)
   {
      // Old checking method...
   }
   else
   {
      bool enable = (bool) license.Enable;
      // New checking method...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it still does not work. I edited the question

Comment: Can you figure an example of XML files, a sample of the old and new license, and method to get the MD5? Then it will be easier to come up with a working solution.